# Is there a way to assign a value of 1 in all rows if any of two value within a group appears in another column?

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by, conditional-statements

For example I have a dataset of NBA ball players. I would like to see who has played for the Nets or Knicks

```
       Name|          Teams|
 Baron Davis        Hornets
 Baron Davis       Warriors
 Baron Davis         Knicks
 Jason Kidd            Suns
 Jason Kidd            Nets 
 Jason Kidd            Mavs
 Jason Kidd          Knicks
Kevin Durant        Thunder
Kevin Durant           Nets
Kevin Durant        Warriors
Michael Jordan         Bulls
Reggie Miller        Pacers
Allan Houston         Knicks
Allan Houston        Pistons
```

Based on this information I would like to assign a value of 1 for each player who has played in the Knicks or Nets and have an outcome

```
       Name|          Teams|      value
 Baron Davis        Hornets           1
 Baron Davis       Warriors           1
 Baron Davis         Knicks           1 
 Jason Kidd            Suns           1
 Jason Kidd            Nets           1
 Jason Kidd            Mavs           1
 Jason Kidd          Knicks           1
Kevin Durant        Thunder           1 
Kevin Durant           Nets           1
Kevin Durant        Warriors          1
Michael Jordan         Bulls          0
Reggie Miller        Pacers           0
Allan Houston         Knicks          1
Allan Houston        Pistons          1
```

All it takes for them is to play for one of two teams to be assigned a 1. If not then assign 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'Name', create the 'value' by checking `any` of the elements in the vector are `%in%` the 'Teams' column to generate a logical vector and it is coerced to binary with `+` or `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Name) %>%
     mutate(value = +(any(c('Knicks', 'Nets') %in% Teams))) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   Name           Teams    value
   <chr>          <chr>    <int>
 1 Baron Davis    Hornets      1
 2 Baron Davis    Warriors     1
 3 Baron Davis    Knicks       1
 4 Jason Kidd     Suns         1
 5 Jason Kidd     Nets         1
 6 Jason Kidd     Mavs         1
 7 Jason Kidd     Knicks       1
 8 Kevin Durant   Thunder      1
 9 Kevin Durant   Nets         1
10 Kevin Durant   Warriors     1
11 Michael Jordan Bulls        0
12 Reggie Miller  Pacers       0
13 Allan Houston  Knicks       1
14 Allan Houston  Pistons      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Baron Davis", "Baron Davis", "Baron Davis", 
"Jason Kidd", "Jason Kidd", "Jason Kidd", "Jason Kidd", "Kevin Durant", 
"Kevin Durant", "Kevin Durant", "Michael Jordan", "Reggie Miller", 
"Allan Houston", "Allan Houston"), Teams = c("Hornets", "Warriors", 
"Knicks", "Suns", "Nets", "Mavs", "Knicks", "Thunder", "Nets", 
"Warriors", "Bulls", "Pacers", "Knicks", "Pistons")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```